# Import-CSV fields as intengers

Tags: powershell, math

I have a CSV which looks like this.

```
server,total,used
server1,1024,512
server2,2048,1024
```

I want to import the csv and divide used by total.  I am getting `invalidopertion: (op_division:string)...` with my current code.  I've attempted to set them as integers both on the import and within the arrays, but it's not working as expected.  Any Ideas?

```
$csv2 = Import-Csv -Header 'server', 'total', 'used' C:\test.csv

$used = $csv2.used 

$total = $csv2.total

foreach($record in $csv2){

$used / $total

}
```

Comment: You don't show an example of the conversion in your code? `$used` would be a string _array_ of all servers in your list. It does not know how to automatically add them together. You don't use `$record` at all in your loop. `Import-Csv  C:\test.csv | ForEach-Object{[int]$_.used / $_.total * 100}`. Your file has a header so you don't need to add one yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's several bugs here.

First, you say that this is your file:

```
server,total,used
server1,1024,512
server2,2048,1024
```

But then you specify headers when you import the CSV:

```
$csv2 = Import-Csv -Header 'server', 'total', 'used' C:\test.csv
```

That means that `$csv2[0]` is going to be the header row from your file.  And you clearly can't divide the string `'used'` by the string `'total'`.  The `-Header` parameter is to be used when there are *no* headers in the file.

Second, when you do this:

```
$used = $csv2.used
$total = $csv2.total
```

You're setting `$used` and `$total` to be an array of values.  Again, you can't divide an array by another array.

Third, you're iterating over the array, but then dividing by the values we set in the above steps.  So you're doing the *exact same operation* for every `$record`.

Try this:

```
$csv2 = Import-Csv C:\test.csv

foreach ($record in $csv2) {
    $record.used / $record.total
}
```

You shouldn't have to worry about converting the string to a numeric value.  PowerShell will try to do that automatically with strings.  As long as it's a numeric string, it will work just fine.

Comment: Forgive me as I am new and this is my first post. I do not have a header in the csv file. I added it to show what each column was.  I am adding the header in the import-csv line.  Your last example worked and I should have noticed this sooner.  I had tried $csv2.used / $csv2.total, but $csv2 should have been $record.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Jmoore983 You are most welcome!  I apologize if I came across as abrupt.  I was simply trying to explain where the errors were.